azure devops pipeline php laravel yaml PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused with 15 error like ,I am already hosting my website on Azure and it is working fine. However, I need to add one CID pipeline using Azure Devops technology stack, which is Laravel.so how to resolve this issue in my piepeline.
